# maven pom.xml exclusion for transitive and normal dependancy

Tags: maven

i tried adding maven dependency directly, say spring context 3.0.7.release
and tried adding spring-context 3.2.8.release(this has also spring context as transitive depedency), how to exclude spring context 3.0.7. is it to comment or to remove or can we use exclusion here?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version} </version>
        <!--    <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for an exclusion here, the version of `spring-expression` you have in your own POM overwrites the other version, and Maven takes care that only one version is used.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i understand tht maven ensures only one version which is nothing but 3.0.7, but i dont want that. i want 3.2.8 only. pls see my modified code snippet of POM and exclusion are commented

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. Why do you add `3.0.7.RELEASE` as dependency if you want `3.2.8`?

Comment: My question is that, if at all i want a scenario like that ,say for instance its needed for logger or something, only in low level version it ll work like that. in that case what to be done

Comment: I still don't understand your problem well. You can have only one version of `spring-expression`. If you write `3.0.7.RELEASE` in your POM, this will overwrite the transitive versions, so if you want a specific version like `3.2.8`, write it into your POM as dependency (or `<dependencyManagement>` entry). If some parts of your code need `3.0.7.RELEASE` and other parts (or dependencies) need `3.2.8`, then you have a huge problem.

Comment: your last line was correct, if few parts need then wat should i do, i know that this ll be problem but still i have to answer back to people....

Comment: The standard solution is to rewrite your code so that it works with the newer version. This may be hard, but everything else is suboptimal. You can also try the maven shade plugin to rename the packages of one of the dependencies, but I have never done that and it is a bit hacky.